# What symbols shows that a device is plugged into a power source?

Tags: symbols, representation

I'm making a very simple diagram of a video camera set-up for my experimental design course. I need to show that a camera plugs into a wall. From a technical perspective, what symbol should I use to represent that? I have a little square to represent the camera, and a line coming out the back to represent the power chord - but obviously that has to be plugged in somewhere.

I know this is not the most correct way to represent this - any advise would be appreciated! Thanks a lot.

Comment: A schematic or a visual would be great!. Do you need the icons for showing ....camera plugs into wall. (Is it related to charging the camera batteries?

Comment: I haven't made it yet - just thinking about it. But to be clear, the entire device itself must be plugged in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it plugs specifically to a wall you could use something like this, which includes both the classic bolt icon and also a **specific plug to the wall**:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

A lighting bolt denotes charging on both iOS and Android.

[image: charging iPhone]

Wall sockets vary country to country, a lightning bolt is synonymous with power.

Comment: Android does it slightly [different](http://forums.androidcentral.com/attachments/android-apps/94796d1386008633t-kitkat-launcher-transparent-statusbar-all-android-4-0-3-4-4-devices-kitkat_launcher_ss1.png).

Comment: I was commenting on the fact a lightning bolt is used as a symbol for power not about the placement of the bolt itself. As per the question, the most obvious representation of that which is widely used, is a bolt.

Comment: And I commented on your answer as a contribution. Neither method is wrong nor better than the other. Thought it could be useful for future references to show how different platforms approach things like these.